# Google maps markers not displayed in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-markers

Since the latest version of Chrome (27.0.1453.93 m / Windows 7) Google map markers in the Chrome browser will no longer be displayed. In IE10 and Firefox everything works fine.

Example (Google code samples):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Is the problem is known and is there a solution?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with Chrome. The Console shows an error on the page load: Uncaught TypeError: Type error
(anonymous function)
CJ.(anonymous function).e.CJ.(anonymous function).j
tJ
a.b
fg.(anonymous function).Y main.js:27
b.b
fg.(anonymous function).Y main.js:27
AJ.(anonymous function).Vc
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) main.js:11
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
Mo.(anonymous function).A
(anonymous function) main.js:10
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) main.js:12

Comment: I posted a problem demo link to [Chrome issue 243994](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=243994) as well as the diagnostics

Comment: Workaround can be found on another version of this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800204/google-maps-markers-not-rendering-in-chrome-v27

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue as problem already solved as I check again today (2013-09-11), with latest version of Chrome ( 29.0.1547.66 m)