# Google Maps Markers not rendering in Chrome v27

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using Chrome v27.0.1453.93. Markers do not render using the latest google maps api version. Markers render in Safari and FF. Chrome development tools indicate an Uncaught Type Error in Line 10 of https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/2/main.js.

I removed the deprecated MarkerImage class but it's still throwing a js error in Chrome.

This used to work. [Implemented url is here](http://nisoa.com/about-us/chapter-locator/).

Anyone else seeing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just updated Chrome to 27.0.1453.94 m; I see markers on your [link](http://nisoa.com/about-us/chapter-locator/)

Comment: Not seeing that version yet for Mac but that's good news. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to this problem: add the parameter optimized: false when you create you marker. I don't know if there are other impacts with this parameter.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
  optimized: false
)
```

Comment: Good one! That did the trick. I actually did have that property set to true.